# Perform tracking using trackPageView or EventTracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics, tracking-extract

We implemented Collect Tracking Code in our website and It's working fine. But beside collecting Page Views we need to be able to collect events triggered by an user/client during the interaction in the website (e.g. clicking and popping up a modal box or other actions perfomed by javascript functions).

I Saw that Collect.js from igoDigital has a function called TrackEvent. Is it possible to use this function to accomplish our requirements?

If not, is there any other option? (It will not be a problem to set these events as a content or a product).

I don't know if my explanation was clear enough but what we pretend to do: install the pixel related with a product/content in one of the pages in our website and also another pixel conditionated to "user interaction", so the IGO_VIEWS will catch first page view and if the user click in this button that opens a modal box another interaction will be populated/counted in IGO_VIEWS.

[image: collect.js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is definitely clear enough. You can indeed "track" your own custom events with Collect. The trouble is, you can't report on them in any way without an engagement with Salesforce's "Customer Success Group" ($). For a price, they can create a trigger/extract to produce files detailing these custom events tracked by Collect and provide these files to an FTP location on a regular basis.

As you mentioned, a hack would be to create dummy "Product" or "Content" items in your Catalog and collect page views in your IGO_VIEWS data extension. Depending on what you're using the data for, alternatives would be to use a third party web analytics provider that can integrate with SFMC, like [Google Analytics 360's integration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_google_analytics_integration_tracking.htm&type=5). It can generate audiences for use in Journey Builder based on events taking place on your site. [Segment.com's integration](https://segment.com/docs/connections/destinations/catalog/salesforce-marketing-cloud/) allows the writing of custom event data to SFMC. Lastly, you could fork Collect.js and create your own middleware on something like Heroku to capture these events and ship the data to SFMC. If volumes of these events are very low, you could forego Heroku and just use CloudPages code resources to capture these events instead.

Comment: Hi Macca, sorry for the late reply, your explanation was very helpful! And helped us to decide what way "to take". Again, thank you!